# should i move to VPS or to dedicated server?

Tags: hosting

I have about 30 web sites, they dont have a lot of trafic like 1500 per monnth each, but use a lot of traffic becouse it is video web sites. Now I am use shared hosting plans, but I want save some money. Becouse shared hosting cost 7euros per month. How can I managed how many rams and CPU I need?

Comment: THe traffic is 1500 WHAT per month? Apples? Oranges? And you think you get a virtuap private server for less than 7 euro per month?

Answer (score 1):

Determine what you need first: Bandwith, Speed, Shell access (?), Price range etc. Then compare the various hosters available.

Unfortunately, you can't really test a company's claims (Speed etc.) until you've set up an account there. So, make sure they've got some sort of test drive available, and don't order anything until you've tried out their products and you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you need to upgrade, just do it. But if your provider has a good service, reliable, very uptime, I think you should not upgrade to VPS. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to go for VPS Hosting if you are looking to save some money, you will get large amount of Space and bandwidth and would work better than shared hosting package. I can suggest you the company I use take a look at **[UK VPS Hosting](http://www.webhost.uk.net/linuxvps.html)**